# Allow alpha_numeric and symbols preg_match PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have the following function

```
public function alpha_custom($str) {
   return (! preg_match("/^([-a-z0-9_-])+$/i", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
}
```

So, if the string contains anything other than alphanumeric characters, underscores or dashes, then it will return false.

Now I want to add the following:

1. `SPACE`
2. `&`
3. `(` AND `)`
4. `.` (period )

Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return (preg_match('/[^a-z_\(\)\.\&\ \-0-9]/i', $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;`

**EDIT**
I have used this to check and it worked for me

```
function alpha_custom($str)
{
   return (preg_match('/[^a-z_\(\)\.\&\ \-0-9]/i', $str)) ? 'FALSE' : 'TRUE';
}

echo alpha_custom('ravi._ &');
```

Comment: still getting failed on `&`